# ResultHandler.print() undefined

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

How come `ResultHandler.print()` is undefined? My Spring version is `3.2.5.RELEASE`.

I am using it as

```
this.mockMvc.perform()...andDo(print());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

print() is defined on `MockMvcResultHandlers` not on `ResultHandler`

From the documentation:

```
 * static imports: MockMvcRequestBuilders.*, MockMvcResultHandlers.*
 *
 * mockMvc.perform(get("/form")).andDo(print());
```

Comment: Thanks! I was too silly to depend on the IDE to automatically import the class containing `print()`

Comment: Happens to the everyone :)